# SQL join to and from dates - return most recent if no match found

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables that I need to join. I have:

```
LEFT JOIN AutoBAF on (GETDATE() BETWEEN AutoBAF.FromDate and AutoBAF.ToDate)
```

and I get the expected result. Now if no matching record is found between the two dates (AutoBAF.FromDate and AutoBAF.ToDate) I would like to join the most recent matching record instead.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

I am using a MS SQL database hosted in Azure.

Small example:

a small example of what I am trying to achieve:

Table **Product**:

```
Product | Description

A       | Product A
```

Table **Price**

```
Product | FromDate | ToDate     | Price

A       | 01-01-20 | 31-01-20   | 100
A       | 01-02-20 | 28-02-20   | 110
```

I need a query that will return the price according to the date returned by GETDATE().

If I run the query 15-01-20 I should get:

```
Product | Description   | Price
A       | Product A     | 100
```

If I run the query 15-02-20 I should get:

```
Product | Description   | Price
A       | Product A     | 110
```

and finally if I run the query 15-03-20 I will have no price in the Price table. Instead of returning null I would like to "fall back" to the most recent known price instead which in this example is 110

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Provide data sample please

Comment: See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the fastest query cause it joins products with all records with future dates. But if your tables are small, it works.

```
SELECT product.product, product.description, isnull(pr_curr.price, pr_fut.price) as price
FROM product 
left join PRICE pr_curr on product.product=pr_curr.product 
and GETDATE() BETWEEN pr_curr.FromDate and pr_curr.ToDate
left join PRICE pr_fut on product.product=pr_fut.product 
and GETDATE() < pr_fut.FromDate 
where pr_fut.FromDate = (
select min(FromDate) from PRICE dates 
where dates.product=pr_fut.product and dates.FromDate>GETDATE()
) or pr_fut.FromDate is null
```

Comment: This one is returning no records.

Comment: @ThomasLundThuen I didn't write the last 'where' condition. Code is just corrected

Comment: Now I get the price - if a price is available with the date interval 01-05-2020 to 31-05-2020. But if I delete this price line I get NULL as price. In the price table the most recent price available is between 01-03-2020 and 31-03-2020. I would like to get this most recent price when no current price is available. Makes sense?

Comment: i did a few minor modifications and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like SQL Server code, which supports lateral joins via the `apply` keyword.  Assuming you want only one match:

```
from product p outer apply
     (select top (1) ab.*
      from autobaf ab
      where ab.product = p.product and
            getdate() <= ab.todate
      order by ab.todate desc
     ) ab
```

Note that this correlates on the `product`, which is not part of your question.

If that is not necessary, then you can use:

```
from t left join
     (select top (1) ab.*
      from autobaf ab
      where getdate() <= ab.todate
      order by ab.todate desc
     ) ab
     on 1 = 1
```

If you know that there is some record in the past, then you can use `cross join` instead of `left join` and dispense with the `on` clause.

Comment: If there is more than one record in the range, he wants all the records. He might need to join the table twice, and `coalesce()` the fields he cares about.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product.product, product.description, isnull(pr_curr.price, pr_fut.price) as price
FROM product 
left join PRICE pr_curr on product.product=pr_curr.product 
and GETDATE() BETWEEN pr_curr.FromDate and pr_curr.ToDate

left join PRICE pr_fut on product.product=pr_fut.product 
and GETDATE() > pr_fut.FromDate 

where pr_fut.FromDate = (
select max(FromDate) from PRICE dates 
where dates.product=pr_fut.product and dates.FromDate<GETDATE()
) or pr_fut.FromDate is null
```